# Finding correlation between 2 variable for 5days

Tags: python

This is my dataset:

[image]

I am new in data analyst, what is the best approach to find the correlation between this two incidents(inc_cnt)?

inc_cnt_bfr is incidents before , inc_cnt_aft is incident after. appid and chg_number comes in pair .

For an example on row 1 , incidents raise is 20 before , incident raise was 70 .

I have came across nearest neighbour(n_neighbour , and metrics='Correlation') and when I look into the documentation, it was confusing to understand . During my training, I covered numpy,pandas and basic ml algorithm. Trying to implement what I have learn but would need some advice on the best approach to find the correlation coefficient or hypothesis testing for this type of datasets
I have implemented two methods as what was advice from @rajith and @Ricardo

```
using panda.corr method , 
# finding correlation using pandas.corr

orrelation between inc_number with panda dataframe 
# Values are discreet

pd_correlation = df["inc_cnt_bfr"].corr(df["inc_cnt_bfr"])
pd_correlation
```

Result : 0.9 which I believed is a strong positive correlation

The other method I have used was spearman method, this however resulted in 0.3 which I assume is a negative correlation

This is how I implemented using spearman method:

Using spearman correlation

Reference :
https://www.statisticssolutions.com/correlation-pearson-kendall-spearman/

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
x = df['inc_cnt_aft']
x_corr = df['inc_cnt_bfr']

corr, p_value = spearmanr(x, x_corr)
corr
```

Both have resulted in different values, how do I determine which is correct for this type of datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are using two methods to calculate correlation.In pandas default method is pearson correlation.

**Pearson correlation evaluates the linear relationship between two continuous variables.**

**Spearman correlation evaluates monotonic relationship**

If you have a idea about the dataset and the what are the features means,and if you think there will be a linear relationship.Go with pearson otherwise Spearman.

you can use pandas [corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) function to find the correlation.

First load your data to a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
correlation = df["inc_cnt_aft"].corr(df["inc_cnt_bfr]")
```

Comment: Thank you @rajith Thennakoon. however , based on the correation, result was 0.9 , I believed that I can say that this is a positive correlation ? are we able to plot the graph out based on the correlation values we get?

Comment: yes it is a positive correlation.for two series correlation is a just a numeric number.if you want to plot autocorrelation,you can use statsmodels plot_acf function to plot correlogram.https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to calculate the correlation coefficient between two random variables, in this case two discrete variables. The [Spearman Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) can be used for this. Assuming your data is loaded into a pandas dataframe `df` you can use `pearsoncorr = df.corr(method = 'spearman')` which will result in the correlation matrix for the columns contained in that dataframe. If you only need the value for those two variables, select only those two columns.

**Update:**
According to the update of the question and given the results of the correlation measures, I suggest that you make a visualization of the data, since I intuit that you have the presence of outliers. There are different reasons why you could be experiencing this difference in value between both measures, one of them is the presence of skewed data or outliers.

Comment: Hi Ricardo , thank you for your input, I have updated the question

Comment: @user12883347 I updated the answer according to the new question